# Is it possible to capture downloaded file from url?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

Couldn't really make a descriptive title, so what I'm after is this:

Our users would need to log in to a service they use (it's something like facebook, so they are logged in nearly all of the time), go to a page, select a menu, click on an item, download a file, and upload it back to our site.

What I've tried is to provide a direct link to the equivalent of the export button in the other service, but they have done their job properly, so cross domain requests, etc are not an option - therefore this returns a `400 BAD REQUEST`. What I **can** do is to set up an `<a href="link-to-file" download></a>` on this element, I trigger a click from our client side javascript, and the users is now able to save nearly all the steps, and just has to reupload the file that has been downloaded.

Now the question: Is it possible that instead of triggering a download for the client's machine, to save the file in memory, to directly upload it to our server?

Or if anyone has any alternatives, that'd be appreciated.

Just for reference, http requests didn't work, as they are signed in to the other app with cookie based authentication, and I don't want to touch that stuff, as It'd possibly give our app permission to act in the name of anyone who clicks a button, and that's not what we're after.

*Disclaimer: This might sound shady at first, but we are really just trying to save steps for the less tech-savvy users, so they could import their already existing data easier.*

Comment: `download=` should respect sop+cors; if you can download the file that way, you can ajax it

Comment: There is no file access in browser javascript to be able to automatically save a file. This is for obvious security reasons

Comment: _"Now the question: Is it possible that instead of triggering a download for the client's machine, to save the file in memory, to directly upload it to our server?"_ Not gathering requirement?

Answer (score 0):

```
    What I can do is to set up an <a href="link-to-file" download></a>
```

ok so this is what i understood.

you are trying to put a download button or something like that.

i think you can do it this way:

since you have the link to the file_to_download_link (link_to_file)

when the user clicks the download button or link, send the link_to_file to the server with ajax. and in server you can download the file or do what ever you want with the link. (you don need to upload it again. just download)